# Ng Bootstrap DatePicker , show next month instead of current

Tags: datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng bootstrap datepicker to set up a calendar.
But my requirement is, instead of the calendar to display the current Month as it does. I need it to display the next Month..i.e January.
I read through the documentation and I can't seem to find a way to customize this.
Is there a way to do this ?
To change the default of the month being displayed ?

It's a basic datepicker :

```
 <ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>
```